# Laravel env() or config() to get environment variable on command line

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, environment-variables

I know that running `php artisan env` on the command line shows me the "Current application environment" (such as "production").

But what I want is to be able to see the value of something like `env('SESSION_DRIVER')` or `config('session.driver')` straight from the command line.

Is that possible?

(I could not find hints in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/configuration#environment-configuration).)

Comment: Here I am coming back to this question again. I always forget about how to use `php artisan tinker`!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can run Tinker:

```
php artisan tinker
```

And then use any of these commands:

```
env('SESSION_DRIVER')
config('session.driver')
```

> Tinker allows you to interact with your entire Laravel application on the command line, including the Eloquent ORM, jobs, events, and more.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/artisan#introduction

Alternatively, you could [create an Artisan command](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/artisan#generating-commands) to show you a value from a config file:

```
php artisan show-config-value session.driver
```

Comment: Thanks! Whoa, interesting: `env('SESSION_DRIVER')` returns `null`, but `config('session.driver')` returns `"file"`. I wonder why `env()` wouldn't find the value.

Comment: Interesting! Thank you so much.

Comment: In laravel 6 while working via ssh i noticed `env('APP_ENV')` command returns null. Use `config('app.env')`

Comment: @gondwe both return null on Laravel 8. Wonder if there's another catch

Answer (score 1):

You can run the **artisan command** in CMD or terminal, which displays the current environment the application is executing

```
php artisan env
```

Comment: This will print the environment type (local/production)